# ViewControllers: What's the difference between present with animation and adding as a child?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I need to present and dismiss a custom view controller that has menu animations. I'm trying to present it modally but having lots of troubles with error messages telling me my begin/end commands are out of balance and etc. It seems like it should be straightforward and it really isn't. So I'm looking at the docs on custom containers and children controllers and etc, and it totally seems like overkill, but if it makes all these errors go away I guess it's worth it.

Comment: They are completely different concepts. You should not replace one by another to work around bugs.

Comment: Can you show us some code? Modal view controllers are pretty simple, so in my opinion you should just debug your current code.

Comment: The code is kind of scattered, which I'm sure is part of the problem. I'd basically have to present almost the entire (big) class, and some of it is NDA. I guess if you have any pointers on tracking down this begin/end imbalance, that would really help. I've been searching and searching my code and I don't see any multiple calls or dismissals.

Comment: Matthias and johnyu, in essence you've answered my question: stick with modal controllers, it should be simple, if it's not, I'm doing something wrong. If you want to post as an answer I'll give you the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

For a view controller’s contents to be visible to the user, it must be associated with a window. There are many ways you can do this in your app:

**Present it from another view controller with animation**

A presented view controller isn’t a specific type of view controller—the presented view controller can be either a content or a container view controller with an attached content view controller. In practice, the content view controller is designed specifically to be presented by another controller, so it can be useful to think of it as a variant of a content view controller.

Most of the time, you present view controllers to gather information from the user or capture the user’s attention for some specific purpose. Once that purpose is completed, the presenting view controller dismisses the presented view controller and returns to the standard app interface.As shown in Image :-

[image]

**Make the view controller a child of a container**

A view controller hierarchy starts with a single parent, the root view controller of a window. If that view controller is a container, it may have children that provide content. Those controllers, in turn, may also be containers with children of their own. [image]

the tab view controller gets its size from the window. It reserves space for its tab bar and gives the remainder of the space to its children. If the navigation controller were the control displayed right now, it reserves space for its navigation bar and hands the rest to its content controller. At each step, the child view controller’s view is resized by the parent and placed into the parent’s view hierarchy.

This combination of views and view controllers also establishes the responder chain for events handled by your app.

Comment: Arpit, thanks for posting the detailed explanation, but it really doesn't address the question. I'm asking, as a novice, for an experienced programmer's opinion of which of the two is more appropriate to my situation. While these details may help inform my ability to choose for myself, they don't actually advise me on that choice. Given what you know about my situation (admittedly incompletely described), do you have a sense of what kind of controller configuration you would use?